# Can't seem to target img via CSS within Nivo Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, nivo-slider

I'm revamping an old/existing website and creating a mobile version in the process. If you view [the site](http://www.seat.uk.com/) in mobile (or via mobile dev tool emulator), you'll see that the main image slider div is responsive, but for some reason, the images inside are not, despite being targeted like this:

```
#slider img {
    max-width: 100vw;
}
```

I have a feeling this has to do with the way Nivo Slider chooses (randomly I presume) slides, and hide/shows them? Don't have much experience with the plugin, so any help would be appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: I never used that Nivo Slider, but I am seeing that the Slider produces "pieces" of the original image, and appends them dynamically to the bottom of the slider, and that is ridiculous... Maybe you have set something up in the settings?

Comment: Yeah, the "pieces" thing is to enable certain transitions and stuff. [Here is a working example](https://www.flynsarmy.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/nivoslider/index.html#) but I haven't figured out how yet...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to answer my own question, but this turned out to be an issue of out-of-date scripts. I grabbed the latest Nivo Slider script [from GitHub](https://github.com/gilbitron/Nivo-Slider), threw it in, and everything is working fine. Apparently responsiveness was built into the plugin sometime between the script I had and the latest (3.2).